# how can i use fetch in pure javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I want to use fetch command in pure javascript file. But i get an error when code execute.
I use visual studio code with code runner extension. Is fetch method only use with node.js or in developer console ? 
How can i use fetch command in pure javascript file ?

`fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5000")
.then(t=>t.JSON())
.then(result=>console.log(result))`

Error Message :

> [Running] node "c:\Users\huseyinoz\Desktop\javatest\tempCodeRunnerFile.js"
>   c:\Users\huseyinoz\Desktop\javatest\tempCodeRunnerFile.js:2
>   fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5000")
>   ^
>
> ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
>       at Object. (c:\Users\huseyinoz\Desktop\javatest\tempCodeRunnerFile.js:2:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)

Comment: you have a typo - `fecth` instead of `fetch`

Comment: Result is same error :( ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Comment: also arrow function is not in vanilla JS. You need to change `() => {}` to normal function declaration

Comment: well guessing the engine does not support it.... import fetch so it can.

Comment: Does you browser [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Browser_compatibility) it?

Comment: What is the browser you use? Refer to this for compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @blaz — Arrow functions are defined in the ECMAScript spect. They are entirely vanilla.

Comment: guessing a bunch of the commenters missed: "I use visual studio code with code runner extension"

Comment: @barbsan blaz — Read the error message. The OP is using Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch` (note spelling) has to be provided by *something*.

It does not exist in the ECMAScript specification, but nor does any form of input or output function. Such functions must be provided by the host environment.

Browsers provide the Fetch API.

Node.js doesn't, but implementations of it are available in packages in NPM.

So pick an implementation (such as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch)).

Install it (`npm install fetch`).

Then import it into your script:

```
const fetch = require("fetch").fetchUrl
```

Comment: Thanks i understand.  i just used in javascript file without nodejs. i don't know browsers provide the fecth API.

Answer (score 2):

Updating answers / comments to status as of **2021**:

### `fetch()` is now defined in ES6:

Javascript ES6 (also known as ECMAScript 2015, ES6 or ECMAScript 6), handles the `fetch()`-API and it is supported by all major browsers.

Documentation at [MDN Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

`fetch()` with all possible options as POST (hence: with body):

```js
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
  mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
  cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
  credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
  referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
  body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
})
.then(response => response.json())
.catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error))
```

### Confusion with CORS issues:

However, many of us are facing troubles when trying to load a JSON from another origin, hence we get error messages and think it has to do with the `fetch()`-API.

Let's analyse in details an Example for a GET request:

URL to a sample JSON file:
https://tools.learningcontainer.com/sample-json-file.json

### 1.) Cross-Origin:

**Mode:** I have put `mode: 'no-cors'` to avoid cross-origin error-message for the `fetch()`-API itself.

**fetch() successful** - it 'finds' the URL (`status: 200`). However,  `"type": "opaque"` in the response header.

**Response empty**:
Response is *empty* though, because of
*Referrer Policy*: `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`
Hence, you will see error message caused by `.json()` (not from `fetch()`):
`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Try and **Run code snippet** and wait for the response in console:

[image: Header of the fetch() request]

```js
fetch('https://tools.learningcontainer.com/sample-json-file.json', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(error => console.log('Error resulting from json(): ' + error))
```

```html
<div id='status'>please wait and watch console for response.</div>

<div id='sampleJson'>
  <p>Trying to catch the following JSON:</p>

  {
    "Name": "Test",
    "Mobile": 12345678,
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pets": ["Dog", "cat"],
    "Address": {
      "Permanent address": "USA",
      "current Address": "AU"
    }
  }
</div>
```

### 2.) Same-Origin:

If the json-file is on same server as your web-page (*same-origin*), `response.json()` would nicely provide the JSON for you to use.

Following the screenshot when placing json file on my web-server and initiating `fetch()` request from my web-page (same-origin):

I've just put following function into my test-html within `<script>` tag:

```js
fetch('./sample-json-file.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

This parses the JSON already into an object, hence you can use Dot notation right away (here: `json.Name` or `json.Address`, etc ...)

[image: Successful response of sample_json_headers]

Works like a charme

Any comments or corrections / suggestions are so welcome - thank you.