# how to fetch a javascript file content and parse it to use it's variables

Tags: javascript, parsing, fetch

I am trying to fetch this javascript file

https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/journal.js

by using a native fetch command like

```
fetch('https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/journal.js').then(v => {
  //do something here
})
```

If the above journal.js is declaring a variable inside it - how can I use that variable in my current scope.

If I console.log(v) - then there is no way of accessing the variable - since chrome shows:

[image]

Is there any way to fetch a javascript file (as text) and then parse it so that we can use the imported file's objects and method in my current scope??

The content of this file declares a variable like:

```
var JOURNAL = [{"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},{"events":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false}]
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid just using a `<script>` tag?

Comment: If you're concerned about the security related in injecting external JS code in your environment, note that you could use a worker (or sandbox) to parse it, and return only the data

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what environment you're targeting? You say you're working with Node.js, but you also say you're using native `fetch` (which doesn't exist in Node.js) and you've shown log output from Chrome. Are you trying to get this data in the browser, or in Node.js?

Comment: yes - sorry - not nodeJS - but  as a singular javascript file which will run in a browser

Answer (score 4):

Use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
fetch('https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/journal.js').then(v => {
  v.text().then(txt => {
    eval(txt)
    console.log(JOURNAL)
  })
})
```

Comment: yes, this works - but only where CORS policy is disabled - from a new google chrome tab - Im getting a CORS error - but it works well from other domain

Comment: CORS is something you should handle on the server side. Add the HTTP header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: @Avraham nice answer, I added some option of fetch() API concerning CORS as @Probosckie mentioned. Are you sure that `console.log(JOURNAL)` would work? I got error message when re-producing: "JOURNAL is not defined"

Comment: @JürgenFink if your `journal.js` file declares a `JOURNAL` variable, it should work. Try to `console.log(txt)` to make sure you get the expected content.

Comment: @Avraham yes, that's what I thought, too. I have posted a more detailed answer concerning **CORS** and `fetch()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68808952/1155234) if you like to review and comment on. Your answer here was very helpful, though. I used it for my own proyect (same-origin) - works like a charme  thank you.

Comment: Yet another comment: answer from @Avraham is nice, because I was not aware of the `eval()` function within the `fetch()` API. I noticed a big **performance increase** when loading a small js script (chart.js 200k) that way, compared to loading it with a promise/http request and then  appending a `<script>` tag as I posted [further down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68764723/1155234)  as an alternative  . Again a big thumbs Up 

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to parse anything, you can also emulate the variables and functions the script requires and then let the browser evaluate the script.

```js
// The script will try to access global in your current environnement
// So we define it and add it to our scope
let wrapped = window.global = {};

// Add the script to the page
$.getScript("https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/journal.js", function(){
  // wrapped now contains the wanted data !
  document.write(JSON.stringify(wrapped));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternative without jQuery:

```
function getScript(source, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var prior = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    script.async = 1;

    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function( _, isAbort ) {
        if(isAbort || !script.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(script.readyState) ) {
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            script = undefined;

            if(!isAbort) { if(callback) callback(); }
        }
    };

    script.src = source;
    prior.parentNode.insertBefore(script, prior);
}
```

Comment: `$.getScript` is a jQuery function; OP has not indicated that they're using jQuery.

Comment: true, but OP can find plenty of other post explaining how to do this without jQuery

Answer (score 0):

### Using Promise:

As alternative solution to answers from @Vinz243 and @Avraham.

```js
function loadScript(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let script  = document.createElement('script');
    script .type = 'text/javascript';
    script.charset = 'utf-8';
    script.async = true;
    script.src = src;
    script.onload = function () {
      resolve(script);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/journal.js loaded';

      // now you have access to the variable 'JOURNAL' (is an array of objects)
      console.log(JOURNAL);
      document.getElementById('events_01').innerHTML = '1: ' + JOURNAL[0].events;
      document.getElementById('events_02').innerHTML = '2: ' + JOURNAL[1].events;
    };
    script.onerror = function () {
      reject(new Error(`Script load error for ${src}`))
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  })
};

loadScript('https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/journal.js');
```

```html
<div id='status'>please wait <br><br>Trying to load file ...</div>
<br><hr>

<div id='events_01'>loading ...</div>
<div id='events_02'>loading ...</div>
```

**Note:**
Solution from @Avraham is very elegant and I use it successfully for other js files in my projects.
However, in this special case I was not able to access the variable **JOURNAL** when reproducing his solution, which was part of the initial question.